# Updated Files Dont Show on Site. I had a cache program installed

Tags: plugin-wp-supercache

Could that be the reason?  I deleted the plugin files but the pages still won't update.  When I edit them from the server I see the updated files, but they don't show on the browser.

Tried deleting cache on browser, still no changes.  Removed cache code from .htaccess, still no changes.  Not sure what else to try.

Thanks.

Comment: Which plugin was it?

Comment: I believe it was WP super cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable the plugin before erasing the files? This happened to me when trying to update a site, I had to end up disabling the cache plugins, then I redid the .htaccess file. Once I completed the updates I simply re-enabled the plugins and modified the .htaccess.